# Why does GCC not optimize this set of branching and conditionals as much as it could?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc

The following three pieces of code achieves exactly the same effect. Yet, when compiled with -O3 on GCC 4.5.2 the times for a lot of iterations vary quite markedly.

#### 1 - Normal branching, using multiple conditions, best time 1.0:

```
// a, b, c, d are set to random values 0-255 before each iteration.
if (a < 16 or b < 32 or c < 64 or d < 128) result += a+b+c+d;
```

#### 2 - Branching, manually using bitwise or to check conditions, best time 0.92:

```
if (a < 16 | b < 32 | c < 64 | d < 128) result += a+b+c+d;
```

#### 3 - Finally, getting the same result without a branch, best time 0.85:

```
result += (a+b+c+d) * (a < 16 | b < 32 | c < 64 | d < 128);
```

The above times are the best for each method when run as the the inner loop of a benchmark program I made. The `random()` is seeded the same way before each run.

Before I made this benchmark I assumed GCC would optimize away the differences. Especially the 2nd example makes me scratch my  head. Can anyone explain why GCC doesn't turn code like this into equivalent faster code?

EDIT: Fixed some errors, and also made it clear that the random numbers are created regardless, and used, so as to not be optimized away. They always were in the original benchmark, I just botched the code I put on here.

Here is an example of an actual benchmark function:

```
boost::random::mt19937 rng;
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> ranchar(0, 255);

double quadruple_or(uint64_t runs) {
  uint64_t result = 0;
  rng.seed(0);

  boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = 
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (; runs; runs--) {
    int a = ranchar(rng);
    int b = ranchar(rng);
    int c = ranchar(rng);
    int d = ranchar(rng);
    if (a < 16 or b < 32 or c < 64 or d < 128) result += a;
    if (d > 16 or c > 32 or b > 64 or a > 128) result += b;
    if (a < 96 or b < 53 or c < 199 or d < 177) result += c;
    if (d > 66 or c > 35 or b > 99 or a > 77) result += d;
  }

  // Force gcc to not optimize away result.
  std::cout << "Result check " << result << std::endl;
  boost::chrono::duration<double> sec = 
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
  return sec.count();
}
```

[The full benchmark can be found here](http://paste.org/39298).

Comment: What is `or`?  Your first example doesn't appear to be valid C.

Comment: It's (at least) a C++ synonym for `||`.

Comment: @Mark B - It is?  Since when?

Comment: About 70% conditions is `true`, I doubt that the third one is better because cpu prefer to guess `true`.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: [Apparently, since forever.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#C.2B.2B_operator_synonyms) They also exist as a set of macros added some time after C89 (not quite C99, it seems - it's weird).

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt C++98 C.2.2.2 `The tokens and, and_eq, bitand, bitor, compl, not_eq, not, or, or_eq, xor, and xor_eq are
keywords in this International Standard (2.11). They do not appear as macro names defined in
<ciso646>`. Also see 2.5/2/table 2 which shows the direct alternate token mappings.

Comment: @Heath since <ciso646> header in Standard

Comment: Example 3 doesn't not appear to be syntactically valid.  It has `result += a * (...) result += a;`

Comment: @Mooing Duck I'm sure that's just a copy-paste error with the final `+=` omitted in the real code.

Comment: I guess the second `+=` operator in version 3 is accidental? Also it would be interesting if that version has the same performance with a ternary operator `?:`.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: What are the types of `result` and `a`?  Are they both primitive types? (eg, no overloads?)

Comment: @MooingDuck: result is `uint64_t` and a, b, c, d are `int`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The OP has changed a bit since my original answer. Let me try to revisit here.**

In case 1, because of `or` short-circuiting I would expect the compiler to generate four compare-then-branch code sections. Branches can obviously be pretty expensive especially if they don't go the predicted path.

In case 2, the compiler can decide to do all four comparisons, convert them to bool 0/1 results, and then bitwise `or` all four pieces together, then doing a single (additional) branch. This trades possibly more comparisons for possibly fewer branches. It appears as if reducing the number of branches does improve performance.

In case 3, things work pretty much the same as 2 except at the very end one more branch may be eliminated by explicitly telling the compiler "I know the result will be zero or one, so just multiply the thing on the left by that value". The multiply apparently comes out faster than the corresponding branch on your hardware. This is in contrast to the second example where the compiler doesn't know the range of possible outputs from the bitwise `or` so it has to assume it could be any integer and must do a compare-and-jump instead.

**Original answer for history:**
The first case is functionally different from the second and third if `random` has side effects (which a normal PRNG would), so it stands to reason that the compiler may optimize them differently. Specifically, the first case will only call `random` as many times as needed to pass the check while in the other two cases `random` will always be called four times. This will (assuming `random` really is stateful) result in the future random numbers being different.

The difference between the second and third is because the compiler probably can't figure out for some reason that the result of the bitwise or will always be 0 or 1. When you give it a hint to do the multiplication instead of branching the multiplication probably comes out faster due to pipelining.

Comment: I'd be interested to see timing difference between `if (rand()>3) ++a` and `a+=(rand()>3)`  Does GCC not do this optimization for some reason?

Comment: @Mooing Duck Is it possible g++ can't determine that the side effects of `++` are the same as from `+=` (pretend you could magically LD_PRELOAD a shared library that changes the semantics of one of those operators).

Comment: +1, and if `random()` happens to call `rand()` then there's no "probably" about it, it's guaranteed to be a PRNG outputting a reproducible sequence for each seed.

Comment: @MarkB: I'd assumed `a` and `result` were primitive types.  If not, then we need a lot more info to answer the question.

Comment: @MarkB: I'm very sorry. You are entirely correct about `random` and it's side effects. I actually had it correct in the original benchmark, but botched it when putting it on here. Your comment about the difference between the second and third is interesting, but I am not entirely sure I get it. Could you deliberate a bit?

Comment: @MarkB: Thanks, very nice answer. It makes a bit clearer to me what the compiler will and won't optimize, at least in this specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

With logical operators the code will branch and early-out. Bitwise operators always do the full job.

Branch prediction will be worse in the first case, although it will outperform the bitwise case for larger examples.

It cannot optimise away `random()` because that function is not [pure](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (idempotent).

Comment: This explains why branches are slower. It does not explain why GCC does not recognize that the branches could have been avoided in the first place.

Comment: Because they *couldn't* have been avoided in the first place, simply put: `random()` changes the behaviour of the program even if you ignore the result. The gcc [pure](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) attribute would enable this optimisation.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but seeing as the original benchmark actually makes all the calls to `random()` before and regardless of what happens in the conditionals, the details of that function becomes irrelevant? My original example had a botched up version of the benchmark in which the side effects of random certainly mess things up.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try optimizing away the branch and multiply. Instead of:

```
if (test) result+= blah;
```

or

```
result+= blah*(test);
```

You can do:

```
result+= blah&(-(test));
```

If `test` is false, `-false==0` and `(blah&0)==0`. If `test` is true, `-true==~0` and `(blah&~0)==blah`. You may have to fiddle with `test` as `!!test` to ensure `true==1`.

Comment: That is a another clever optimization concept I haven't noticed before. +1

Comment: This kind of micro-optimisation is best left to the compiler.

Comment: @spraff: That's what I thought about the branching stuff. Are you saying for example GCC will recognize that blah*(test) is always multiplying by 1 or 0 and will optimize it as above? I already spent my frivolous research allowance for this week, so I won't be testing this myself.

Comment: I don't know if it *will* but it *could*. It's more important that the next *human* can read it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (Intel E5503) with gcc 4.5.3, I find that version 1 is generally the fastest, though the difference is well within the measurement noise (f3 is the slowest, though only about 2% slower than f1).

How are you measuring your timings?  You might find that the differences you're seeing are due more to that than the actual difference in the code produced.

Comment: I posted a link to the actual benchmark; it puts several conditionals per loop to emphasize that part of the computation. Requires boost 1.47. I'd be interested in seeing if your results still differ.